# What is the meaning of sanskrit word प्रज्ञा(prajna) according to scriptures

Tags: scripture, meaning

1. What is the work of प्रज्ञा(pragna)?  For E.G work of buddhi(बुद्धी) is to make decisions.
2. How does it helps us in leading a ideal life?

According to maharishi charak in charak samhita says
प्रज्ञाअपराध leads to diseases!

Comment: You should explain your doubt properly. This one-liner doesn't help much as regards with a prospective answer.

Comment: @yes you can check now

Answer (score 4):

Prajna can be interpreted as the wisdom beyond worldly reasoning and inference

Reference:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prajna_(Hinduism)

From Tattva bodha , SVSSS of HH Adi Shankaracharya, we see that the Abhimani(identify with) of sthula(gross) sharira is termed vishwan, and that of sukshma( subtle) sharira is termed Taijasan . Only when
the Prani is in the  state of sushupti transcending gross and subtle  it is called prAjnyan.

Reference:
TB verse 6. 3 chinmaya mission
3.1 Atha sushupti avasthaa kaa? Then what is the Deep Sleep State?
.2 “Aham kimapi na jaanaami”, “I do not know anything”,
.3 “Sukhena mayaa nidraa anubhuyate” “A good sleep was enjoyed by me”;
.4 Iti sushupti avasthaa. such a state is called Deep Sleep.
.5 Kaarana shareera abhimaani
aatmaa “Praajna” iti uchyate.
Identifying Itself with the causal body,
the Self is called “PRAJNA”

Reference: Bhagavad Gita 2.11

aśhochyān-anvaśhochas-tvaṁ prajñā-vādānśh cha bhāṣhase
gatāsūn-agatāsūnśh-cha nānuśhochanti paṇḍitāḥ

Here Prajna Vada , is the wisdom beyond vyavaharik (worldly) inference

Reference: Bhagavad Gita 2.54
sthita-prajñasya kā bhāṣhā samādhi-sthasya keśhava
sthita-dhīḥ kiṁ prabhāṣheta kim āsīta vrajeta kim

Sthitha Prajna is steady  supreme wisdom which is transcendent

PrajnA is also seen in Mahayana buddism vocabulary , as prajna parimitha meaning perfect wisdom beyond worldly inference

Reference:

https://www.britannica.com/topic/Prajnaparamita-Buddhist-literature

PrajnA Parimitha is also seen in Mahalakshmi saharanama

Reference :
https://sanskritdocuments.org/